# How can I retrieve quotient of value in aggregation from Mongodb 3.0?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, mongodb-aggregation

Mongodb 3.2 supports `$divide` and `$floor` operator. So, in version 3.2 I just use that operator. But in version 3.0, only the `$divide` operator is provided.

`$divide` operator calculates quotient which is decimal not integer.

How can I get the quotient which is integer value not decimal?